# How do I send my output xls files to a specific path in python?

Tags: python, pandas, path

How do i make my df.to_excel function write to an output path? After my script runs, I do not see the files in the output_path directory i have defined.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import datetime

output_path = 'C:/Users/g/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Processed'

path = 'C:/Users/g/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching'

cols_to_drop =  ['PSI ID','PSIvet Region','PSIvet region num','Fax','County']               
 
column_name_update_map = {'Account name': 'Company Name','Billing address':'Address','Billing city':'City','Billing State':'State'} 

for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/g/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching"):
    if file.startswith("PSI") and "(updated headers)" not in file:
        dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None,skiprows=5)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws.startswith("Cancelled Members"): df = df.drop('Active date', axis=1)
            if any(ws.startswith(x) for x in ["New Members","PVCC"]):
                continue
            #if ws in ["New Members 03.22","PVCC"]:   #sheetstoavoid
            temp = df
            dt = pd.to_datetime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path,file)),unit="s").replace(nanosecond=0)
            output[ws] = temp
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file.replace(".xlsx","")} (updated headers).xlsx')
        for ws, df in output.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

I tried `df.to_excel(writer,output_path, index=None, sheet_name=ws)`

But i get an error
File "", line 36, in 
df.to_excel(writer,output_path, index=None, sheet_name=ws)

TypeError: to_excel() got multiple values for argument 'sheet_name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments:

- The function `os.listdir()` only returns "unqualified" file names, so before using `file`, we need to prepend `path` using something like `input_file_name = f'{path}/{file}'`.
- Similarly, `pd.ExcelWriter()` will need a qualified file name (that is, including the path as well as the "unqualified" file name), which we can get by doing this: `output_file_name = f'{output_path}/{file.replace(".xlsx","")} (updated headers).xlsx'`.
- There are some elements of the code in your question that may not be getting used, but rather than comment on or change those, I provide a working version with minimal changes below.

I created directories named `Matching` and `Processed`. I placed a file named `PSI 123.xlsx` in `Matching` with a tab named `Cancelled Members` containing the following:

```
will skip           
will skip           
will skip           
will skip           
will skip           
Col1        Col2    Col3    Active date
xx          NY      110     789
```

I then ran the following modification to your code (note the changes to `output_path` and `path` for testing purposes in my environment):

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import datetime

#output_path = 'C:/Users/g/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Processed'

#path = 'C:/Users/g/Desktop/autotranscribe/python/Matching'

output_path = './Processed'
path = './Matching'

cols_to_drop =  ['PSI ID','PSIvet Region','PSIvet region num','Fax','County']               
 
column_name_update_map = {'Account name': 'Company Name','Billing address':'Address','Billing city':'City','Billing State':'State'} 

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith("PSI") and "(updated headers)" not in file:
        input_file_name = f'{path}/{file}'
        dfs = pd.read_excel(input_file_name, sheet_name=None,skiprows=5)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws.startswith("Cancelled Members") and 'Active date' in df.columns: df = df.drop('Active date', axis=1)
            if any(ws.startswith(x) for x in ["New Members","PVCC"]):
                continue
            #if ws in ["New Members 03.22","PVCC"]:   #sheetstoavoid
            temp = df
            dt = pd.to_datetime(os.path.getctime(os.path.join(path,file)),unit="s").replace(nanosecond=0)
            output[ws] = temp
        output_file_name = f'{output_path}/{file.replace(".xlsx","")} (updated headers).xlsx'
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_name)
        for ws, df in output.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

After running, the code had created a new file in `Processed` named `PSI 123 (updated headers).xlsx` with sheets named as in the input. The sheet `Cancelled Members` contained the following:

```
Address State   Zip Status  Status.1    Date    Partner
Col1    Col2    Col3
xx      NY      110
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. I added one change from our previous thread - output_file_name = f'{output_path}/{file[:3]}_Processed(updated headers).xlsx'

Comment: constantstranger sorry for taggin you again. not sure why no one has answered this question of mine today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191076/how-do-i-concatenate-files-that-have-multiple-sheets-with-same-column-headers-bu Please let me know if this is something you have insight in